# Dynamic div positions don't change depending on different screen resolution

Tags: jquery, html, css, position, screen-resolution

I have dynamic divs that can have different positions, widths and heights. The information about the divs, I save it in the database and I call it using php. But when I use a different screen resolution I have a different position in the parent div. I use jQuery to change the position and size of the parent div. How can i solve this problem?

**Here I have a photo of the problem** : [image]

**and how it looks in full size:**
[image]

**another display with smaller resolution:**

[image]

```js
$('.box').each(function() { $('.box').draggable();});
$('.box').each(function() { $('.box').resizable();});
```

```css
#lager {
    height: 750px;
    border: 5px dotted #292929;        
}

.box {
    background:rgb(107, 193, 243);
    cursor:move;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    
<div class="row">
    <div id="boxid" class="col-xs-12">
    <!-- hier die Position änder -->
    </div>
</div>
<!--here I start the foreach -->
    <div id="id" class="box" style="top:50px; left:50px; width:50px; height:50px;">           
        <p id="top"></p>
        <p id="left"></p>  
        <p id="height"></p>
        <p id="width"></p>          
    </div>
<!--here I end the foreach -->
```

Comment: Have you tried setting your children's position relative to parent?

Comment: @TheWanderingMind you mean inside  the div?

Comment: Yes. If I understood your issue correctly, you have a parent div that contains children divs (your dynamic divs). Have you tried setting your dynamic divs' position to relative? This way, when one of your dynamic divs has `top: 50px`, for instance, it will be positioned 50px from the top of your parent and not from the top of the page.

Comment: @TheWanderingMind i understood that. But the problem is that this divs must to be after the div soo that you can move them to the parent.

Comment: @TheWanderingMind i tried your idea and i have problem there. When i change the div size it change the position of the next div.

Comment: Could your provide a fiddle to help me better guide you?

Comment: @TheWanderingMind https://jsfiddle.net/cristiannn/ztf7pry6/6/

Comment: If you set your "boxes" to `display: inline-block;`, you will notice that the adjacent boxes won't move vertically, but will move horizontally so they don't overlap. Is that what you're looking for or do you want to allow overlapping?

Comment: @TheWanderingMind no i don't want to allow overlapping, i just want that the boxes move with the container, if you understand what i mean?

Comment: @TheWanderingMind loog here i upload it on my website http://myworkbook.nl/try . Play with resolution to understand it. Like mobile resolution, full scree resolution...

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean. It's a tricky situation. Because your boxes' positions are absolute, they are positioned relative to their nearest positioned parent, which is your document body, and not your container. So when your container shrinks because the resolution changed, the boxes will continue being positioned relative to the body.

Comment: What you could do is to move the dragged box in the container when it is dragged in it.  So you could use the droppable widget to detect when your box is dropped in the container and when it is, move that box in the container. Also, you'd have to change your boxes' position to relative so they are positioned relative to the container.

Comment: @TheWanderingMind can you please give me an example how can i do it? I mean code. And put it as answer and i will accept it.

Comment: Maybe tomorrow, I don't have much time today unfortunately. I encourage you to try to  do it yourself if possible.

Comment: @TheWanderingMind thx i will wait for it tomorrow.

Comment: I don't have a lot of time today neither, so I won't post an answer, but here is a [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/yataqirege/) you could play with. It gives you and idea of how to snap a box in the container, but it's not perfect; the new positions must be tweaked.

Comment: @TheWanderingMind i tried your solution, thx for it, is good but why i use **position:absolute;** is because of div moving. If you use **position:relativ;** then first div will move the second div, and for a dynamic field is not a good idea.

Comment: If you place your dynamix boxes in a relative positioned container and set your boxes' position to absolute, it fixes this issue. [Here is the edited fiddle](https://jsbin.com/foyexokive/edit?html,css,js,output).